# Consume webservice before FullCalendar starting render

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar built-in method "viewRender" to load my webservice with month content this way:

```
$scope.viewRender = function (view, element) {
    $("td").removeClass("fc-today");
    $("td").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");

    var currentMonth = view.intervalEnd._d.getMonth();
    var currentYear = view.intervalEnd._d.getFullYear();

    ScheduleAttendanceSrvc.getCalendar(1, currentMonth, currentYear).then(
        function (calData) {
            window.calData = calData;
        },
        function (statusCode) {
            toastr.warning("Calendar Data doesn't exist.");
        }
    )
}
```

And I'm using FullCalendar built-in method "dayRender" to customize FullCalendar's appearance this way:

```
$scope.dayRender = function (date, cell) {
    var formattedDate = date._d.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

    if (($.inArray(formattedDate, window.calData)) > -1) {
        cell.context.bgColor = '#0aa699';
    } else {
        cell.context.bgColor = '#f35958';
    }
};
```

The problem is that i have no guarantee that viewRender will always run first than all dayRender. In fact, view Render runs between all the dayRenders. Is there a better way to load my webservice before dayRender runs, since I depend on my webservice return to customize it's appearance?

Thanks so much.